# Error en Base de datos

Tags: java, android

estoy creando una base de datos, y este es el código que tengo en JAVA:

```
 String strNombre = nom.getText().toString();
            String strPregCinco = preg5.getText().toString();
            String strPregCuatro = preg4.getText().toString();


            if(strNombre.matches("") || strPregCinco.matches("") || strPregCuatro.matches(""))
            {
                Toast.makeText(context,"¡Dejaste campos vacíos!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            else if(botonun.isChecked() == false && botondo.isChecked() == false && botontr.isChecked() == false && botoncu.isChecked() == false && botonci.isChecked() == false
                    && botonse.isChecked() == false && botonsi.isChecked() == false && botonoc.isChecked() == false && botonnu.isChecked() == false && botondi.isChecked() == false
                    && botonon.isChecked() == false && botondc.isChecked() == false)
            {
                Toast.makeText(context,"¡No marcaste ninguna respuesta!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            else if(db != null)
            {
                db.execSQL("INSERT INTO Encuestado (strNombre, strPregCinco, strPregCuatro, ) " +
                        "VALUES (" + strNombre + ", '" + strPregCinco + ", '" + strPregCuatro + "')");
                Intent pas = new Intent(encuesta.this, MainActivity.class);
                Toast.makeText(context,"¡Encuesta enviada!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                startActivity(pas);
            }
            db.close();
```

El problema está en el `else if(db != null)`, ya que antes no lo tenía y todo funcionaba perfecto.

Cuando le doy al botón "Enviar encuesta", se ejecuta la condición if/else if, y cuando se ejecuta el `elseif(db != null)`, aparece el crash, y la aplicación se detiene, necesito ayuda! Gracias.

Comment: Tus `else` terminan mal: `else if(db != null)`... el último debe ser un `else`... de lo contrario no termina de preguntar. Mira un ejemplo:  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/displayCode.html?code=https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/examples/IfElseDemo.java La idea de concatenar elses es que, si no se cumplen todos los anteriores, al final, no queda nada que preguntar. Si tu código está bien concebido, en este caso, si no se cumple nada de lo anterior, tu `db != null` es verdadero sí o sí, por tanto no hay ni que preguntarlo, sino ejecutar el `INSERT`

Comment: Lo puse así: `else
                {
                    String nombre = "Pablo";
                    db.execSQL("INSERT INTO Encuestado (nombre) " +
                            "VALUES (" + nombre +"')");
                    Intent pas = new Intent(encuesta.this, MainActivity.class);
                    Toast.makeText(context,"¡Encuesta enviada!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    startActivity(pas);
                }
                db.close();` Y aun asi, sigue sin funcionar, la aplicación se detiene.

Comment: No entiendo el sentido de : `String nombre = "Pablo";` Ya tienes tu variable `strNombre` más arriba. Si sigue dando error sería bueno que edites la pregunta poniendo la parte relevante del mensaje de error, en caso de que sea muy largo, bastaría con que pongas las líneas alrededor de `Caused by...`

Comment: Si, ya quite el `strNombre` y puse `nombre`, y ahora tengo error en esta línea: `(this, "DBEncuestado", null, 1);`. Dice esto: `encuestadoSQLiteHelper() in encuestadoSQLiteHelper cannot be applied to ` Y después esto: `android.content.Context
this  (anonymous...view.View.OnClickListener)`

Comment: Y... en mi caso, aunque no sea motivo de error, para evitar la evaluación de múltiples `.isChecked()` usaría algo así como una variable de tipo Boolean supongamos que se llame `bolSeleccionado` la cual apagaría o encendería (true o false) cuando al menos una de las opciones haya sido marcada. De este modo evaluaría sencillamente `bolSeleccionado` es verdadero o falso, ahorrándome todos los `.isChecked()` que hay en tu código.

Comment: ¿Cuál es el sentido de `Intent pas = new Intent(**encuesta.**this, MainActivity.class);` ?, ¿no debería ser: `Intent pas = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);`? Mira los códigos de ejemplo de Android:  https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html?hl=es

Answer (score 0):

Tu tienes el `db.close()` fuera de la prueba si db es `null`. Eso te causa una `NullPointerException` en el caso que `db==null`. Usa un `try... catch` o mantiene el cierre dentro de la condición.

Comment: Ya meti el db.close() dentro de la condición, y aun así, voy a storage/sdcard/data y no aparece la base de datos que creé.